# assign 2 variables in 1 command

Tags: bash, shell

I have bash script that prints me table: timestamp, value1, value2, and ratio between value1/value2. For example:

```
2022-08-07 21:00  2784000/8750=318
2022-08-07 20:00  2792000/8760=318
2022-08-07 19:00  2790000/8760=318
2022-08-07 18:00  2776000/8750=317
2022-08-07 17:00  2804000/8570=327
2022-08-07 16:00  2799000/8580=326
2022-08-07 15:00  2783000/8590=323
2022-08-07 14:00  2729000/8580=318
2022-08-07 13:00  2638000/8530=309
2022-08-07 12:00  2637000/8490=310
2022-08-07 11:00  2610000/8450=308
2022-08-07 10:00  2595000/8470=306
2022-08-07 09:00  2616000/8490=308
2022-08-07 08:00  2604000/8470=307
2022-08-07 07:00  2619000/8450=309
2022-08-07 06:00  2626000/8530=307
2022-08-07 05:00  2627000/8530=307
2022-08-07 04:00  2634000/8530=308
2022-08-07 03:00  2626000/8470=310
2022-08-07 02:00  2625000/8530=307
2022-08-07 01:00  2676000/8540=313
2022-08-07 00:00  2654000/8590=308
2022-08-06 23:00  2673000/8610=310
2022-08-06 22:00  2641000/8570=308
2022-08-06 21:00  2655000/8610=308
2022-08-06 20:00  2665000/8670=307
2022-08-06 19:00  2672000/8670=308
2022-08-06 18:00  2626000/8680=302
2022-08-06 17:00  2581000/8690=297
2022-08-06 16:00  2581000/8720=295
2022-08-06 15:00  2560000/8720=293
```

Now after sorting it basing on value on right side of '=' `./script.sh | cut -f2,2 -d= | sort  -n` . Now I want to assign max and min. Ofc its easy to assign max as output of last line, and min as 1st line but assigning 2 variables leads to 2 executions of `script.sh`. Is there any smarter way to fetch max and min without printing output 2 times?

Comment: If you instead provided us with the raw data, perhaps an even more efficient way to get what you want would appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any command that prints only the first and last line (e.g. `sed -n '1p;$p'`) then read both lines into an array using `mapfile`, or put both lines into a single one with a separator that does not appear in the input, and `read` two variables.

```
IFS=' ' read -r min max < <(./script.sh |
  cut -f2,2 -d= | sort | sed -n '1p;$p' | tr '\n' ' ')
```

That would be one way to do it. But as Ted Lyngmo commented: There is most likely a more efficient way depending on the content of `script.sh`.
Even now, we could do without the `sort` (probably the costliest part of your pipeline) when using a custom script that retrieves the min and max in a single unsorted pass, e.g. something like ...

```
IFS=' ' read -r min max < <(./script.sh |
  awk -F '=' -v min=999999 -v max=-999999 '
  $2<min {min=$2} $2>max{max=$2} END {print min, max}')
```

Comment: Hi! that is good. Just please explain why we need '-r' ?

Comment: @linux_beginner [read without -r will mangle backslashes](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2162). Assuming that the output only contains numbers and nothing else, you don't need `-r` or `IFS=' '`. But its a good habit to use it anyways. Expect the unexpected ;)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding another subprocess call we can replace the current `cut/sort` with a single `awk` call to extract `min/max`:

```
./script.sh | awk -F= '
FNR==1 { min=max=$2 }
       { min=($2<min ? $2 : min)
         max=($2>max ? $2 : max)
       } 
END    { print min,max }'
```

This generates:

```
293 327
```

Feeding to `read` to populate the `bash` variables:

```
read -r min max < <(./script.sh | awk -F= '
FNR==1 { min=max=$2 }
       { min=($2<min ? $2 : min)
         max=($2>max ? $2 : max)
       }
END    { print min,max }')

### or collapsing into a single line:

read -r min max < <(./script.sh | awk -F= 'FNR==1{min=max=$2}{min=($2<min?$2:min);max=($2>max?$2:max)}END{print min,max}')
```

Both of these generate:

```
$ typeset -p min max
declare -- min="293"
declare -- max="327"
```

**NOTE:** if the purpose of `script.sh` is to generate some output to be parsed for `min/max` then a better approach may be to modify `script.sh` to just generate the `min/max`; on the other hand if `script.sh` output is to be used for multiple purposes then consider redirecting stdout to a file and then parsing said file as needed

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mawk 'BEGIN {     _+=_ ^= FS = "="; OFS = "\f"
>                ___=-(__ = ++_^_^_ ) 
>       }    { __=(_= +$NF )<__ ?_  :__
>           ___=___<_?_:___  } END { print _=____,__,___,_ }'
> ```

```
293
   327
```